# Violin plot in d3

Tags: d3.js

I need to build a violin point with discrete data points in d3.

Example:

[image: weight vs group discrete violin plot]

I am not sure how to align the center for each value on X axis. The default behavior will overlay all the points with same X and Y value, however I would like the points to be offset while being center aligned e.g. 5.1 has 3 values in control group and 4.5 has 2 values, all center aligned. It is easy to do so for either right or left aligned by doing a transformation of each point by a specified amount. However, the center alignment seems to be quite hacky.

A hacky way would be to manually transform the X value by maintaining a couple of arrays to see whether this is the first, even or odd number of element and place it according my specifying the value. Is there a proper way to handle this?

The only example of violin plot in d3 I found was [here](http://bl.ocks.org/z-m-k/5014368) - which implements a probability distribution rather than the discrete values which I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A hacky way would be to manually transform the X value by maintaining a couple of arrays" - that's pretty much the way most d3 layouts work :-) . Discretise your data set by the y value (weight), keeping a total of the data points in each discrete group and a group index for each datum. Then use those to calculate offsets x-ways and the rounded y-value.

See https://jsfiddle.net/n444k759/4/

```
// below code assumes a svg and g group element are present (they are in the jsfiddle)
var yscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10]).range([0,390]);
var xscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,2]).range ([0,390])
var color = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0,1]).range(["red", "blue"]);
var data = [];
for (var n = 0; n <100; n++) {
    data.push({weight: Math.random() * 10.0, category: Math.floor (Math.random() * 2.0)});
}

var groups = {};
var circleR = 5;

var discreteTo = (circleR * 2) / (yscale.range()[1] / yscale.domain()[1]);
data.forEach (function(datum) {
    var g = Math.floor (datum.weight / discreteTo);
  var cat = datum.category;
  var ref = cat+"-"+g;
  if (!groups[ref]) { groups[ref] = 0; }
  datum.groupIndex = groups[ref];
  datum.discy = yscale (g * discreteTo);    // discrete
  groups[ref]++;
});
data.forEach (function(datum) {
 var cat = datum.category;
    var g = Math.floor (datum.weight / discreteTo);
  var ref = cat+"-"+g;
  datum.offset = datum.groupIndex - ((groups[ref] - 1) / 2);
});

d3.select("svg g").selectAll("circle").data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return 50 + xscale(d.category) + (d.offset * (circleR * 2)); })
  .attr("r", circleR)
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return 10 + d.discy; })
  .style ("fill", function(d) { return color(d.category); })
;
```

The above example discretes into groups according to the size of the display and the size of the circle to display. You might want to discrete by a given interval and then work out the size of circle from that.

Edit: Updated to show how to differentiate when category is different as in your screenshot above

Comment: This is great! Can you please explain a bit about the discretization? I am a bit confused about the `discreteTo` variable?

Comment: Basically it works out for a given circle size (`circleR * 2`), a given display height (`yscale.range()[1]`) and a given data domain (`yscale.domain()[1]`) what to round each 'weight' value to so the circles pack nicely together vertically - the nearest quarter, the nearest unit etc. Too large a rounding and there's gaps, too small and the circles overplot each other. The little formula there works that out. Of course if your data is already discrete then what you might need to work out the circle size from the range, domain and size of the discrete interval (0.1 in your picture).